# Replace at the given position (i,j) with a value passed to the procedure as an argument

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I had something like this, it sort of makes sense to me but I've figured there is most probably something wrong with it, I'm really new to VB and any help will do.

```
Private Sub replaceArray(ByVal repValue As Integer) As Integer (,)

Dim intI, intJ As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 to  intI.GetUpperBound(0)

    For i = 0 to intJ.GetUpperBound(0)
        replaceArray(intI,intJ) = repValue
    Next 

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your loop formation is incorrect

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? is it for fill a two dimensional array with `repValue`?

Comment: @TusharGupta having a look at it

Comment: @NeethuSoman yes that basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim a(5, 5) As Integer
a = replaceArray(1) ' call function to initialize array with `1`
Private Function replaceArray(ByVal repValue As Integer) As Integer(,)
    Dim b(a.GetUpperBound(0), a.GetUpperBound(1)) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To a.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j As Integer = 0 To a.GetUpperBound(1)
            b(i, j) = repValue
        Next
    Next
    replaceArray = b
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your function is of array type, there is nowhere in it an array is actually created. You will need to create one and to do this you'll also need to know how large it should be. Given this you can create it and fill it and return it. Something like:-

```
Private Function replaceArray(ByVal repValue       As Integer,
                              ByVal horUpperBound  As Integer,
                              ByVal vertUpperBound As Integer) As Integer (,)

Dim new_array(horUpperBound, vertUpperBound) As Integer

For i As Integer = 0 to new_array.GetUpperBound(0)

    For j As Integer = 0 to new_array.GetUpperBound(1)
        new_array(i, j) = repValue
    Next 

Next

Return new_array

End Sub
```

Comment: cannot return a value from `sub`, you need to use `Function` instead for this

Comment: Thanks, that has helped a lot

Comment: its ok i removed the -1,have a nice time